# Reverse char array using pointers

Tags: c++, reverse

Can't understand what's going on in the `while` If possible visualize, please.

```
int main() 
{

        char text[] = "hello";
        int nChars = sizeof(text)-1;

        char *pStart = text;
        char *pEnd = text + nChars - 1;

        //can't understand this part 
        while (pStart < pEnd)
        {
            char tmp = *pStart;
            *pStart = *pEnd;
            *pEnd = tmp;

            pStart++;
            pEnd--;
        }

        cout << text << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code is swapping characters in the string. It's but not clear to me what is your problem exactly?

Comment: there is no problem with the code. can someone  explain how this small code works.

Comment: Debug to see the change in values of the variables after each statement.

Comment: what don't you understand about that part exactly? Mentally process it one line at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple swapping mechanism. Inside while loop your code is swapping the values. See the attached picture.

[image: Inside the while loop swapping is happening]

Comment: Thank your. I knew it's simple

Comment: Welcome,, do not forget to tick the green mark if your problem was solved

Comment: Done. Took me 5 min to find the checkmark wich you mentioned. I'm new here and in programming too.
CHEERS!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is simple swapping characters in `text`. What happens here is :-

1. You create a character array `text` of size 6 storing "hello\0".
2. `nChars` as you have assigned represents the number of characters in text other than `\0` so here it is 5 (similar to `strlen`).
3. `pStart` is pointed to the first letter of text (ie 'h') while `pEnd` to the 'o' (not `\0`).
4. First `tmp` is assigned with 'h'. Then `pStart's` character is replaced with that of `pEnd` ie 'o'. Then `pEnd's` character is assigned with that stored in `tmp`. Thus characters in `pStart` & `pEnd` are swapped (but the pointers are still pointing to the same location, be careful here !).
5. `pStart` is incremented & `pEnd` decremented (location wise not character wise, again be careful here !!). So now `pStart` points to 'e' & `pEnd` to 'l'.
6. The procedure repeats !!!